# python3.4.4 import tkinter wrong

Tags: python, tkinter

I installed tkinter from yum,but I can only use it in Python2.

This is in Python3:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

and I can use "import Tkinter" in python2.

But how i can use it in Python3, Thanks.

Comment: which python distribution you are using. Most of them have tkinter inbuilt.

Comment: maybe `yum install python3-tkinter`

Comment: @np.array Oh, thinks,it's Python3,and according ur suggestion,i rebuild Python3.4 and it worked.Maybe something wrong when i installed.:)

Comment: @Ivan i had installed ,but maybe something wrong happend, i rebuild Python3 now and successed,thanks

Answer (score -1):

Install python3:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

If you have already done that, ge the setuptools:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get upgrade python3-setuptools
```

After which install tkinter:

```
sudo -H pip3 install tkinter
```

Comment: In the question, he used `yum`, your answer uses `apt`.

Comment: He has. I've seen it. But, the main point is getting tkinter to work. I did it and this is a way to solve the problem...